# How to combine multiple lists with streams and lambdas indicating where there is a duplicate

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am attempting to reduce several collections into a single collection using streams and lambdas.  However I need to indicate wherever a duplicate hit occurred.

Basically I have the following situation:

Collection 1 of Customers (All Persons)

```
Person 1 (Tom)
Person 2 (Bob)
Person 3 (Joe)
```

Collection 2 of Prospects

```
Person 1 (Mike)
Person 2 (Wilbur)
Person 3 (Joe)
```

Collection 3 of Employees

```
Person 1 (Mike)
Person 2 (Tony)
Person 3 (Sue)
Person 4 (Joe)
```

I would like to transform this collection to include a new field which I can do using Map - where I am getting lost is actually how to flatten it so that the final result would be something like this

Collection

```
Person 1 (Tom, "Customer")
Person 2 (Bob, "Customer")
Person 3 (Joe, "Customer, Prospect, Employee")
Person 4 (Mike, "Prospect, Employee")
Person 5 (Wilbur, "Prospect")
Person 6 (Tony, "Employee")
Person 7 (Sue, "Employee")
```

I am just planning to create a string value to represent visually which areas they belong in.

Thanks!

[EDIT]

Based on the suggestion below, I was able to test out the solution this way...

class TestOutFlatMap {
    public void test() {

```
    Map<String, Collection<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();

    Collection<Person> p1 = new ArrayList<>();
    p1.add(new Person("Mike"));
    p1.add(new Person("Joe"));
    p1.add(new Person("Tony"));

    Collection<Person> p2 = new ArrayList<>();
    p1.add(new Person("Wilbur"));
    p1.add(new Person("Joe"));
    p1.add(new Person("Molly"));

    Collection<Person> p3 = new ArrayList<>();
    p1.add(new Person("Wilbur"));
    p1.add(new Person("Joe"));
    p1.add(new Person("Bubba"));

    map.put("Customer", p1);
    map.put("Prospect", p2);
    map.put("Employee", p3);

    Map<Person, String> output = map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(t -> t.getValue().stream().map(g -> new Pair<>(t.getKey(), g)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.getValue(), u -> u.getKey(), (x, y) -> x + ", " + y));

    output.keySet().stream().forEach(p -> {  
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(output.get(p));
    });

}
class Person {
    String name;

    Person(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString () {return this.name;}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

};

}
```

However my results weren't as expected.  They returned as follows:

```
Bubba 
Customer 
Molly 
Customer 
Wilbur Customer, Customer 
Tony Customer
Joe Customer, Customer, Customer 
Mike Customer
```

I am not seeing where it's concatenating incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try grouping, with a downstream collector to convert the group into a String, like this:

```
        Map<Person, String> result = map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(v,e.getKey())))
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,         // group Map.Entry by key
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,      // for each group, convert Map.Entry into the value 
                    Collectors.joining(","))));              // convert the values into a comma-delimited String
```

If it is somehow possible that the same `Person` could be found twice under the same category key, and you would like unique categories for each `Person`, you could collect each group to a `Set` to make the group elements unique, and then convert the `Set` to a `String` with `Collectors.collectingAndThen` like this:

```
        Map<Person, String> result = map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(v,e.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.toSet(), x -> String.join(",",x)))));
```

With the following setup,

```
        Map<String, Collection<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Person person1 = new Person("Person1");
        Person person2 = new Person("Person2");
        map.put("Customer", Arrays.asList(person1, person2));
        map.put("Prospect", Arrays.asList(person1));
        map.put("Employee", Arrays.asList(person2, person2));
```

I get`{Person1=Customer,Prospect, Person2=Employee,Customer}`

Comment: Thanks for the tip - unfortunately both give me a compile error at the collect "inference variable K has incompatible bounds" and this one "the type of <R,A> collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>) is errorneous"

Comment: Thanks, @purringpigeon, I had the wrong type for `map`. I corrected my answer

Comment: This is weird - When I run the first example I get the same results...  The collector concatenates the same string over and over...   Joe "Customer, Customer, Customer" rather than what I was expecting of Joe, "Customer, Prospect, Employee".  The second example collapses the string to just say "Customer".

Comment: The only way you should see duplicate keys in the first example is if you have the same Person multiple times in the same list.  Check the `equals()` function in your `Person` class--perhaps all of your instances of `Person` are logically equal?

Comment: @purringpigeon, I updated my answer to show how I set it up. I used the implementation of `Person` you provided in your example.  You should change the `hashCode` function, btw.

Comment: Thanks - I looked at my initial code... I loaded up the wrong array in the sample - so it was a typo.  Couldn't see that until I got your response.  Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

As you have multiple collections with different type, you should have some identifier for each collection. So best way to represent your input as Map of collection, where key of the map represents the type of collection such as Customer, Prospect and Employee.

Now, given that you have a `Map<String, Collection<Person>>,` you need to group by each element of the collections, and track associated key. For this, you need to use flatmap.
Following code should work:

```
    Map<String, Collection<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Customer", ...);
    map.put("Prospect", ...;
    map.put("Employee", ...;

    Map<Person, String> output = map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(t -> t.getValue().stream().map(g -> new Pair<>(t.getKey(), g)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                t -> t.getValue(), u -> u.getKey(), (x, y) -> x + ", " + y));
```

Please note the Pair class is used from [javafx.util.Pair](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html).

Comment: Actually this didn't work.  It almost worked.  I got the following result for example: Joe, "Customer, Customer, Customer".  I did get the correct values in the map for the keys.

Comment: Well, your code is incorrect. You are creating 3 collections, p1, p2, p3. But adding elements into p1 always. Try correcting it, and you will get right output.

Comment: Yup - I saw that on the other post - chased that issue all day.  Thanks.